# How to print in sunmi V2

Tags: java, android, printing

I'd like to print something that looks like this

[image]

**the machine used is Sunmi V2**
I've checked up their sample but it was an array of bytes, I've no idea about how to print:

- line
- text in the center
- third type of **total 50**

so, can anyone suggest to me or guide me?

Answer (score 1):

You can take these all into some variables, then use SUNMI print function.

In Java:

```
final String outerSep = "\n---------------------------------\n";
string total = "Total:"+"                    "+"150" //6char+22spaces+3char = total 31 char
```

Please note that actually there is a total of 31 character spaces in each line. So you can arrange the lines by co-ordinating strings with blank spaces.

Then don't forget to start the printer by `initPrinter()`
At last print each line by the code `printText(printing-line)`

For more details, you can refer the documentation: http://ota.cdn.sunmi.com/DOC/resource/re_en/SunmiPrinter%20Developer%20documentation.pdf

Comment: this is not accurate as it won't work perfectly on multiple paper sizes